# RS-232 Client using pySerial

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, pyserial

I'm trying to write an RS-232 client application which connects to a device and reads some information, currently there is a Win32 application to do the same and I want to make it portable by creating a python app which does the exact same thing. I ran a serial data capture(portmon.exe) software to see what kind of Tx Rx packets are there and I'm trying to recreate them using my python code, without much help. When I compare the portmon.exe output between my python app and the Win32 app, I can see some differences especially on the initial port setup part. So if any of you can help me better understand the following request response dump, it would be great,
 TIA! 
**Request Response Dump from win32 app:**

```
0  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IRP_MJ_CREATE  Serial0  Options: Open 
0  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
1  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE  Serial0  
1  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
2  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  
2  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
3  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_CHARS  Serial0  
3  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
4  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW  Serial0  
4  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
5  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE  Serial0  
5  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
6  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  
6  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
7  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_CHARS  Serial0  
7  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
8  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW  Serial0  
8  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
9  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE  Serial0  Rate: 9600
9  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
10  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_CLR_RTS  Serial0  
10  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
11  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_CLR_DTR  Serial0  
11  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
12  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  StopBits: 1 Parity: NONE WordLength: 5
12  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
13  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_CHAR  Serial0  EOF:0 ERR:0 BRK:0 EVT:0 XON:11 XOFF:13
13  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
14  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW  Serial0  Shake:0 Replace:0 XonLimit:2048 XoffLimit:512
14  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
15  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_LSRMST_INSERT  Serial0  Char: ffffffff
15  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
16  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_QUEUE_SIZE  Serial0  InSize: 8192 OutSize: 100
16  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
17  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_TIMEOUTS  Serial0  
17  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
18  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS  Serial0  RI:-1 RM:0 RC:0 WM:0 WC:0
18  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
19  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_DTR  Serial0  
19  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
20  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_RTS  Serial0  
20  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
21  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  
21  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
22  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  StopBits: 1 Parity: NONE WordLength: 8
22  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
23  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  
23  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
24  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  StopBits: ERROR Parity: NONE WordLength: 8
24  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
25  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  
25  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
26  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  StopBits: ERROR Parity: EVEN WordLength: 8
26  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
27  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE  Serial0  Rate: 9600
27  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
28  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK  Serial0  Mask: RXCHAR CTS DSR RLSD ERR RING 
28  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS  
29  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_WAIT_ON_MASK  Serial0
```

**Request Response Dump from python app:**

```
0  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IRP_MJ_CREATE  Serial0  Options: Open 
0  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
1  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_QUEUE_SIZE  Serial0  InSize: 4096 OutSize: 4096
1  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
2  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_TIMEOUTS  Serial0  
2  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
3  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS  Serial0  RI:0 RM:0 RC:0 WM:0 WC:0
3  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
4  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_WAIT_MASK  Serial0  Mask: ERR 
4  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
5  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE  Serial0  
5  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
6  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  
6  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
7  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_CHARS  Serial0  
7  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
8  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW  Serial0  
8  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
9  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_BAUD_RATE  Serial0  
9  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
10  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  
10  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
11  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_CHARS  Serial0  
11  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
12  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_GET_HANDFLOW  Serial0  
12  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
13  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_BAUD_RATE  Serial0  Rate: 9600
13  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
14  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_RTS  Serial0  
14  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
15  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_DTR  Serial0  
15  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
16  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  StopBits: 1 Parity: NONE WordLength: 8
16  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
17  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_CHAR  Serial0  EOF:0 ERR:0 BRK:0 EVT:0 XON:11 XOFF:13
17  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
18  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW  Serial0  Shake:1 Replace:40 XonLimit:2048 XoffLimit:512
18  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS  
19  4:23:35 PM  python.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_PURGE  Serial0  Purge: TXABORT RXABORT TXCLEAR RXCLEAR
19  4:23:35 PM  SUCCESS
```

Comment: If you are concerned about the differences, it would help to be able to see both traces.

Comment: sure, have edited the question adding the trace for the python code as well... thanks!

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the trace of the win32 application also shows Tx Rx data packets (rather than just these setup calls), but the Python script stops? The most important items in the setups appear to match so where is it failing? The trace is showing you the Windows driver log. These called are documented on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes you are right, the windows app however does a few things more than the python script `12  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL  Serial0  StopBits: 1 Parity: NONE WordLength: 5` and `15  4:22:29 PM  ntvdm.exe  IOCTL_SERIAL_LSRMST_INSERT  Serial0  Char: ffffffff
15  4:22:29 PM  SUCCESS ` , I'm unable to set this char in python as there are no APIs to do the same. The windows application is successfully able to read/write data onto the com port whereas my python code is unable to do the same and gets stuck in the read call.

Comment: A couple of other difference are that the Win32 app is setting the WordLength twice, first time for 5 bits and second time for 8 bits before starting to read/write data. It is also setting a Queue size, again for which there is no API in pyserial.

Comment: I would guess you do not have to worry about that, I have seen other applications do this. They sometimes first configure defaults, and then later configure the required values. One idea would be to connect your serial port to another PC using a cross over cable with a terminal emulator running on it. You can then simulate data in both directions.